# Sharing CAD files via a MediaWiki wiki

Tags: mediawiki

I can upload CAD files to a MW wiki after adding the line

> application/dwg dwg

to the file include/mime.types and allowing uploads for the file extension in LocalSettings.php.

But then if a page includes a link e.g. Lorem ipsum [[file:some_plan.dwg]] dolor ... it shows as an ugly  text link

> Lorem ipsum file:some_plan.dwg dolor ...

Clicking on this link goes instead to the file description page.

How is it possible to share non-image files via a MW wiki and to have:

a) Only a file name alias to appear as a link?

b) An icon to show with the link to indicate it's CAD file?

c) The CAD file to download with one click on the link?

d) Also allow users to upload these files?

Comment: Please read [the docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Links), they answer half your questions.

Answer (score 1):

a) To pipe a file name to some alias, preface file: with a colon e.g.

> Lorem ipsum [[:file:example.dwg|some name]] dolor ...

b) For an icon to indicate a file-type. This only works for external hotlinks. Edit MediaWiki:Common.css similar to how it's done for links to PDF files.

c) See b) then use the [filepath](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:MediaWiki_file_usage#Uploaded_media_files) magic word e.g.

> Lorem ipsum [{{filepath:example.dwg}} some alias] dolor ...

d) Users upload files as usual